# How does this single lever shower tap work internally?

Tags: faucet

I'd like to understand what's going on with my shower before deciding how to tackle the problem.
I apologize if this is the wrong stack for it.

My shower has a single lever "Zetamix 2000" tap: it's made of a round part united to a downward-protruding lever.
You rotate the whole thing clockwise or anticlockwise to get hot or cool water (*I will call this "clock angle"*), you pull the lever towards you to increase water flow and you push it towards the wall to reduce it.

I think part of the cartridge is failing and while I'm pretty sure I just need to change it, my brain can't quite understand how it's working.

Starting a few months ago, if the lever is at a certain clock angle and you move it by just a bit to the left or to the right, the water flow cools down (*a lot!*) instead of warming up and vice-versa.
To get water at a different temperature you need to move it to a very different clock angle and then bring it back. Then, if you've over corrected, the right thing to do is to slightly move it in the theoretically wrong direction.

Mom says that she closes and opens the tap again once the lever is at the right clock angle, but I think it's just that the hot water pipe might have cooled down a bit and the whole system needs a few seconds to get freshly heated water from the nearby boiler again.

What's the usual flow inside the cartridge, and how has wear changed it so that it does what I tried to explain?

I've made a quick image search and according to the results, the cartridge inside the mixer should look like this:

[image: Zetamix 2000 cartridge]

Comment: "*I think part of the cartridge is failing and while I'm pretty sure I just need to change it, my brain can't quite understand how it's working.*" It is not  necessary for you understand how it works in order to replace it. **Is this a DIY Home improvement question**, do you need to know how to replace it?

Comment: Single lever shower controls can be squirrely (hi-tech term). They are not very precise especially as they age. Partly it's wear and partly scale buildup from hard water that interferes with the flow. Personally, I don't like them in a shower because a slight movement of the handle can take the temp to an irritaing and maybe dangerous extreme. There are better options out there.

Comment: What kind of water heater do you have?

Comment: @AlaskaMan This is exactly why I was not sure I should have asked here. Where else can I find people with experience on those parts?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it's a condensing boiler, AFAIK

Comment: Honestly, it's a structural problems with the question:  It's a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/338621) but I'm sadly doing the same thing, what I mean to ask if whether it's tanked (lots of hot water til it runs out, then nada) vs tankless (unlimited hot water up to a certain flow rate, then weak tea). Also I should ask more about how the piping is routed (e.g. in the walls, under the house, under a crawlspace etc.)

Comment: it's called a cartridge because when it goes bad you replace the whole cartridge.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have no idea. I think it just has a bigger tank than the last one we had ages ago (I've never ran out of hot water with this one). I can open the front panel, how do I check? (The red tank at the back is just the expansion tank I guess). The piping goes either into a wall or into the floor (there's a hot/cold couple going into each) - it's brick walls as usual here in Italy.

Comment: @Zachiel Photos would be a start Do you own this house and heating plant?  Or is this a condo/apartment where a management maintains it?